# Potential employer is uncontactable

Tags: interviewing, communication, job-search, job-offer, follow-up

I have recently applied to position X at a company. However they saw that I was more interested in field Y as listed on my CV so also put me forward to position Y which I previously did not see on their job listings page.

Soon after I applied, they invited me for telephone interview for position Y - which I thought went somewhat shaky but they dropped clues that I was likely to go for face to face interview. Meanwhile I received an email that I had not got position X that I originally applied for, understandable as the telephone interview indicated that position Y would be much more suitable. After the telephone interview I was emailed a problem to return to them and I completed this on the day, getting back an email to inform me they would be in contact soon to inform me whether I am through to the next stage. Great! Near 2 months have passed and I have heard nothing. Whilst I have sent an email and rang many times whilst never anyone picking up. All the time going through to voicemail.

Should I keep phoning them and hope to get through or just assume the dead silence means I did not get through to the next stage?
How can I get a firm yes or no answer?

Comment: I thought it is different in that I have already tried to reach out to the company but I haven't managed to get a response at all. Although the answers are relevant - thanks

Comment: I imagine there are other, similar (closed) duplicates. Take the hint (both here, and from the employer stonewalling you).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have your firm answer. It has been two months and they are not interested in your application.  I'm sorry - some companies just don't care about informing candidates that they haven't been successful.

It's time for you to forget this company and move on.

If they do (eventually) come back to you - do you really want to work for people who treat potential employees with such disrespect?